# Flask-SocketIO Error during websocket handshake Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: heroku, flask, websocket, socket.io, flask-socketio

This seems similar to some unanswered questions on stack overflow.

I am running a python socketio app on heroku and I get this error when I launch the website :

Error during websocket handshake Unexpected response code: 400

I kept thinking this was a flask-socketio error but reading similar problems online makes me think this is a socketio error. Any one knows how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by following this link https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1147

Apparently gunicorn 19.x has issues working with websockets. Downgrading to 18.0 worked.